# JQGrid create dropdown cell with values depended from row id

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I have the following JQgrid which is working fine.

```
                $("#Groups_UseCases_Grid").jqGrid({
                    url: 'groupsHandler.ashx?mod=3',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'GET',                 
                    loadonce: true,
                    height: 'auto',

                    width:'750px',
                    colNames: ['id', 'groupname', 'workSpace'],
                    colModel: [
                            { name: 'id', index: 'id', key:true, width: 200, sortable: false,  editoptions: {readonly: true,size: 10}},
                            { name: 'groupname', width: 200, sortable: false, editable:false },
                            { name: 'workSpace', width: 400, sortable: false, editable:true , edittype:"select",editoptions:{multiple:true, size:"<%=combolistSize%>", value:"<%=combolist%>"} }                             
                              ],                                              
                    rowNum: 30,
                    rowList: [30, 60, 90],
                    pager: '#pager',                
                    sortname: 'id',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    sortorder: 'asc',
                    caption: 'Groups UseCases Ascosiation Grid', 
                    editurl: 'groupsHandler.ashx?mod=3', 
                    hidegrid: false,
                    altRows:false,                 
                    altclass:'myAltRowClass',                    

                    grouping:true,
                    groupingView : {
                    groupField : ['useCase'],
                    groupText : ['<b> useCase : {0}  (Records {1}) </b>']

                }
                });             

                 jQuery("#Groups_UseCases_Grid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",
                    {edit:false,add:false,del:false});  
                jQuery("#Groups_UseCases_Grid").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager", 
                  {edit:true,add:false,del:false},
                   {afterSubmit: function(rowid, aData){document.forms[1].submit();//alert("row id is "+rowid)
                        }},   
                        {closeAfterEdit: true,reloadAfterSubmit: false},
                        {closeAfterAdd: true,reloadAfterSubmit: false},

                        {reloadAfterSubmit: true});
```

`C# code :
private string combolist;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

           combolist =create_combolist();

        }

    }

 private string create_combolist(/string groupID/)
        {.....}`

My problem is that i want column workSpace values to be generated by giving the id of the selected row as it depends on it and narrows the dropdown valuelist 
Is it possible using the onSelectRow?
I tried 

`onSelectRow: function(id){<%usecasesample.create_combolist(); <%combolist = usecasesample.create_combolist();%>; } ,` 

that works too but i cant supply row id in it.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance,
alex

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine

```
        $("#Groups_UseCases_Grid").jqGrid({
                        url: 'groupsHandler.ashx?mod=2',
                        datatype: 'json',
                        mtype: 'GET',                 
                        loadonce: true,
                        height: 'auto',

                        width:'850px',
                        colNames: ['groupid', 'groupname', 'workspaces'],
                        colModel: [
                                { name: 'groupid', index: 'id', key:true, width: 200, sortable: false,  editoptions: {readonly: true,size: 10}},
                                { name: 'groupname',index: 'groupname', width: 200, sortable: false, editable:false },
                                { name: 'workspaces', width: 400, sortable: false, editable:true , edittype:"select",editoptions:{multiple:true, size:"" }}


                                  ],                                                                      
                        
                         onSelectRow: function(id) {                          
                            var name='workspaces';                                 
                            jQuery("#Groups_UseCases_Grid").setColProp(name, { editoptions: {multiple:true,  dataUrl: 'groupsHandler.ashx?mod=3&rowID='+id }})                                    

                        },

                        
                        rowNum: 30,
                         cellEdit:false,
                        rowList: [30, 60, 90],
                        pager: '#pager',                
                        sortname: 'id',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        sortorder: 'asc',
                        caption: 'Groups UseCases Ascosiation Grid', 
                        editurl: 'groupsHandler.ashx?mod=2&rows=20&page=1', 
                        hidegrid: false,
                        altRows:false,                 
                        altclass:'myAltRowClass',                    

                        grouping:true,
                        groupingView : {
                        groupField : ['useCase'],
                        groupText : [' useCase : {0}  (Records {1}) ']

                    }
                    });             

                     jQuery("#Groups_UseCases_Grid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",
                        {edit:false,add:false,del:false});  
                    jQuery("#Groups_UseCases_Grid").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager", 
                      {edit:true,add:false,del:false},
                       {afterSubmit: function(rowid, aData){document.forms[1].submit();//alert("row id is "+rowid)
                            }},   
                            {closeAfterEdit: true,reloadAfterSubmit: false},
                            {closeAfterAdd: true,reloadAfterSubmit: false},
                            {reloadAfterSubmit: true});
```